# The [xps] tag... What is it intended to refer to?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, tags

I just noticed that the [xps](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/xps) tag seems to refer to two different things: the Dell computer series, and the `.xps` [file type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_XML_Paper_Specification). Which was it intended to refer to, and if one, should the tag be removed from questions about the other?

Answer (score 6):

It's hard to say whether it was ever "meant" for one or the other; at this point it's a bit of a mess but they're mostly about the filetype. I'm going with [xps](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/xps) for the file type, and retagged questions about the Dell laptops to [dell-xps](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dell-xps), which already has a lot more questions than [xps](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/xps) does.